# Matrix multiplication MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, digraphs

So maybe I am overthinking this and making a mess of it....

I have a digraph in MATLAB. I need to change it to a undirected graph to evaluate it with minimum spanning tree (right? It won't work on digraph). I have a nx1 matrix of binaries (1 is unique, 0 is repeat) that denote repeats, and my node-node-edgeweight matrix is in the form nx3. It seems my directed edges are the same either directions, so changing it to undirected shouldn't make a difference.

How can I use the column vector of binaries to zero out all three columns of repeats in my main matrix, so it will only show undirected edges?

Also, if there is another approach I am missing, I would love that!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of what you're trying to obtain.

Comment: Sorry, I am on my phone here at work. But here is the idea: [1;0;1] × [3 3 2; 5 4 1; 8 2 2] will give me [3 3 2; 0 0 0; 8 2 2]

Comment: so are you simply looking for `x.'.*y` or `x.*y` ? (where .`.*` represent the element wise multiplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example:

```
vect = [1;0;1]; % n x 1
mat  = [3 3 2; 5 4 1; 8 2 2]; % n x p
```

First idea

```
out = repmat(vect,1,size(mat,2)).*mat;
```

Second idea

```
out = mat;
out(find(~vect),:) = 0;
```

## For MATLAB >= r2007a

(from [Chris Luengo comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405883/matrix-multiplication-matlab/49411896#comment85827588_49411896))

```
out = bsxfun(@times,vect,mat)
```

## For MATLAB >= r2016b

(from [Chris Luengo comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405883/matrix-multiplication-matlab/49411896#comment85827588_49411896))

```
out = mat.*vect
```

Comment: Instead of `repmat`, prefer `bsxfun`: `bsxfun(@times,vect,mat)`. In newer version of MATLAB, and in Octave, you can simply do `vect.*mat`, there is implicit expansion of singleton dimensions.

Comment: I didn't know that. Reading [mathworks](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop), this is true for version >= 2016b.

Comment: I always forget which versions introduce new features, so I just say "newer versions" and try to get away with that. :p